# Java multithreading - awaiting condition and releasing all threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a relatively simple issue to solve, namely I would like to make all threads await a certain condition to happen and then proceed. It can be explained by the code below:

```
void doSth(){ //shared by multiple threads
...
if(!conditionMet())
    await();

//procceed further
resetCondition()
}
```

I do not want to use locking and conditions, as it seems unnecessary. `CountDownLatch` would be perfect, but I have to reset the latch, and `CyclicBarrier` would not work either because I have no idea how many threads need to call await. Also, when the signal is sent to awaiting threads, they should all be released and proceed. How would you guys approach this?

Comment: How come you don't know how many threads there are?

Comment: I don't know as this method is called by external threads and I have no idea on their numbers. What I would like to have is a class where I can call a method `await()` which will block the thred, and then `signal()` that will release all blocked threads at once

Comment: What is it that releases the threads?  Does another thread call `release()` or does a thread who tests `conditionMet()` and gets `true` release any other threads waiting?

Comment: I have been thinking about the following: Set a different countDownLatch before singalling the ones being currently waiting. That should release all of the waiting ones and restart the awaiting phase. What d you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html)

> I have no idea how many threads need to call await.

For each thread that eventually needs to wait, invoke `phaser.register()` [register doesn't wait, it tells the phaser to expect another thread to either wait or to trip the barrier]

> CountDownLatch would be perfect, but I have to reset the latch

Once a thread completes, invoke `phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance()`.  At that point, all threads will wait there until the `number of threads registered == number of threads arrived`.

Comment: @Gray With Java 6 already having reached end-of-support, hopefully this is not a problem for any new code written.

Comment: Sure @Marko.  But my company, for example, hasn't switched yet.  I wonder what the 7+ adoption rate is.

Comment: @Gray According to [this source](http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/09/12/software-stack-market-share-august-2012/), it was at 80% a year ago.

Comment: That's from a particular software vendor however @MarkoTopolnik.  God knows if they had features only available in 7.  I would think it was less than that but I have no data to back that up.  Here's a link which said in May 2012 the adoption rate was 23% not 80%.  https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/java_7_adoption_at_23

Comment: @Gray Yes, saw that link as well, and they include a report from the same source as my link, belastic. So the same source reported 20% in May and 79% in September. Also they all seem to comment that the uptake rate is surprisingly high.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thank you for that information.  I am hoping the general public will be either moving soon or starting development with Java 7 so that there doesn't need to be a distinction between Java 7 and any other versions.

Comment: @JohnVint Oh, but there will be a distinction very soon, and a much larger one---between Java 7 and Java 8!

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to use locking and conditions, as it seems unnecessary.

Why?  This smacks of premature optimization to me.  If you don't know how many threads there are then you can't use `CountDownLatch`.  This seems to me to be a perfect use case of standard locks and conditions.  The only time we worry about their use is when we are trying hard not to get threads to block.  But in this case blocking is exactly what you want.

Comment: OK, in this case, if multiple threads get the lock, figure out the condition is false, and then await a signal, how can I make sure that when the signal is sent, all of them would be able to proceed? They would all need to reacquire the lock, check the condition and perhaps some of them will proceed, some will not, as the condition might change by that time, and I want all of the threads to proceed when the signal is sent

Comment: precisely, so one will get it, then the next, and then the next and so on, so they cannot proceed all at once. I would like sth similar to what I described in my comment above

Comment: I have no good answer @Bober02.  You could do it with a little bit of code but I suspect `Phaser` does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you wouldn't want to use locks? Any "barrier" mechanism will internally use some form of synchronization, so there's no real "unleash all threads at the same time" solution.

Best I can come up with:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

void doSth() { //shared by multiple threads
    ...
    synchronized(lock) {
        while(!conditionMet()) {
            lock.wait();
        }
    }
}

void release() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        resetCondition();
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}
```